# I want my Ubuntu on an external display alone?

Tags: display

I have a toshiba laptop with ubuntu 12.04 on it and I've connected it to an external display but I don't want to mirror the displays nor make it stretch on both I just want it show up on my external display only !! Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to **System Settings > Displays**, you will see two different displays: one will be your laptop, and one will be your external monitor.

Select the laptop monitor, and flip the switch to 'off.' Then select the external monitor and make sure the switch is set to 'on.' Afterwards, click on the 'Apply' button and verify that only your external monitor is now displaying.

Comment: Than you too :D

Answer (score 2):

Run (in terminal) `xrandr -q`

Find out which connected output you want to disable (in this example we disable LVDS1) and then:
`xrandr --output LVDS1 --off`

Example output of `xrandr -q`:

```
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x800       59.9*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       70.1     60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        66.7     60.0
```